# Question about the hint and answer.(inequality,and the relation between hint and question itself)

Tags: probability, inequality, chebyshev-function

Question:

Given two sequences of random variables {$X;n=1,2,...$} and {$Y;n=1,2,...$} and a random variable $X$,suppose that with probability one $|X_n-X| \le Y_n$ all $n$ and that $E[Y_n] \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Prove that $E[X_n] \to E[X]$ and that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability as $n \to \infty$

Hint:

$E[X_n] \to E[X]$ means $|E[X_n]-E[X]| \to 0$,try to prove $Pr(|E[X_n]-E[X]| \gt 0)$ with Chebyshve’s inequality.

Solution:$|E[X_n]-E[X]| \le E[|X_n-X|] \le E[Y_n] =0$,that means,$E[X_n] \to E[X]$

By Chebyshve’s inequality $Pr(|E[X_n]-E[X]| \gt \epsilon) \le \frac{E[|X_n-X|^2]}{\epsilon} \to 0$

$\mathbf {Here}$ $\mathbf {are}$ $\mathbf {my}$ $\mathbf {are}$ $\mathbf {question}$ $\mathbf {about}$ $\mathbf {the}$ $\mathbf {hint}$ $\mathbf {and}$ $\mathbf {solution}$

1.The question wants me to prove   $E[X_n] \to E[X]$ and that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability as $n \to \infty$,but i can't understand why do i have to prove $Pr(|E[X_n]-E[X]| \gt 0)$ with Chebyshve’s inequality?Do they have some relation?

2.I can't understand why $|E[X_n]-E[X]| \le E[|X_n-X|]$,which inequality does the author use?

3.According to the information about Chebyshve’s inequality in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality ,why is it $\le \frac{E[|X_n-X|^2]}{\epsilon}$,but not $\le \frac{E[|X_n-X|^2]}{\epsilon ^2}$

Comment: 1) I am not sure as well. I suspect it was a typo - $\Pr\{|E[X_n] - E[X]| > \varepsilon\} \to 0$. 2) Jensen inequality, or you just need to note that $|X_n - X| \geq X_n - X$. 3) Again it maybe a typo, but it does not matter.

Comment: @BGM But when i prove $Pr{|E[X_n]−E[X]|>ε}→0$,why it can also prove   $E[X_n]→E[X]$ and that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability as $n→∞$?

Comment: $E[X_n]$ is a sequence of real numbers and $E[X]$ is a real number.  What is $Pr(|E[X_n]-E[X]|)$ supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem/"solution" it is from a book, I don't think it's a good book.

The convergence in probability is $\operatorname{Pr}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\to 0$

$\operatorname{Pr}(|E[X_n]-E[X]| \gt 0)$ does not make any sense.

Comment: @BGM told that may be a typo,but i still don't understand why we can prove $E[X_n] \to E[X]$ by proving $Pr|X_n -X| \gt ε \to 0$

Comment: $\operatorname{Pr}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\to 0$ is used to prove the convergence in probability, not convergence in mean. The proof of the convergence in mean is just $|E[X_n]-E[X]| = |E[X_n-X]| \le E[|X_n-X|] \le E[Y_n] \to 0$. But Chebyshev's inequality assumes finite variance, which is not assumed by your problem. The way to correctly prove convergence in probability from convergence in mean (without assuming finite variance) is by using Markov's inequality, not Chebyshev's. Both the hint and the solution are a mess. I recommend you to stay away from such material.